# Move margins of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to move all the subplots a little to the right, so that there is more space before the zero on x-axis. The `margins` results in symmetrical spacing. How can I do this?

Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 4, 2]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[1].plot(x, y)
ax[0].margins(0.3)
ax[1].margins(0.3)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say more space, do you mean more space on the plot itself or between the plot and the borders of your figure?

If you mean within the plot itself, you can just manually set x-axis (though I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 4, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[1].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_xlim(-4,6) #however much space you want
ax[0].set_xticks([0,1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Since you're setting `sharex=True`, you don't need to specify for `ax[1]`.

Also, if you have a larger range of datapoints and want set xticks more easily, you can do:

```py
import numpy as np

#linspace(start,end,num_steps)
set_xticks(np.linspace(0,3,4))
```

Comment: Margins inside the plot, but I don't want to have more ticks than the ones I have. Your example insert the ticks [-4,-3,-2,-1, 4,5]. That's why I use `margins`

Comment: @Pedro you can use ax[0].set_xticks([0,1,2,3]) to remove extra ticks. Editted to show this. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The margins method changes [the padding on the limit of your axes by scaling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html). If you want specific values for your limits that will give you the right level of asymmetry you can use (for example)

```
ax[0].set_xlim(-0.99, 3.2)
```

Comment: I don't want extra ticks.

Comment: You can manually set your ticks. A way to not have to mess around with ticks is to set the limit to a decimal just before the next tick e.g. ax[0].set_xlim(-0.99, 3.2)